# Excel function Implemented on Access

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

I am working on a "inventory check" Excel worksheet that finds the item code and then inserts a timedate in a the date column.

Table has two Columns; 'Item Code' and 'Date'

I have made a macro on Excel that basically asks for item code, and inserts the date in the corresponding cell.

I am trying to implement this in Access. Does anyone have any references?

Comment: Excel and Access are very different. Spreadsheets and relational table-stores are only superficially similar. Do you mean want to run `UPDATE Inventory SET Date = @date WHERE Code = @code`?

Comment: Yes, but how can we make it so that a user can type the item number. Will this function work using forms in Access?

Comment: You need to create a form in order for the user to interact with the data and run vba code.  Running code in Access is not the same as running a macro in Excel.  It depends on how you want the user to interact and whether you want them to see the item before marking it as checked.  The simple way is to create a form with a textbox and a button.  Try some code and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of Access so I'll try to be generic:

In Access - find the table and create a form from it (Usually by clicking a button on the toolbar).

Switch to design view in the form, in the header add a combo box using the control wizard and ask it to "Find a record in my form based...." - set it to the field "Item Code"

Set the visible property of the item code box in the detail section to False

create a macro to set a property - control is "Date", property to set is "Value", value to set it to is "=Now()"
Save this macro

Add a command button, in the wizard set it to run your saved macro